# HTTP Basic Authentication for phantomjs in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, selenium, phantomjs, basic-authentication

I'm currently developing a script where users can access a page and scrape data from it.
Problem is, it has an `HTTP Basic Authentication`.

At first I was using the `http://user:password@site.com` and it works. But when the password contains special characters besides the `Base64`, it doesn't login.

I am using `phantomjs` and `watir-webdriver` for this script.

I already tried this code:

```
caps = { 'phantomjs.page.settings.userName' => 'admin', 'phantomjs.page.settings.password' => 'password' }
browser = Watir::Browser.new :phantomjs, :desired_capabilites => caps
```

sometimes it works, sometimes not.

I also tried the custom headers:

```
caps = {'phantomjs.page.customHeaders.Authorization'=> "Basic " + Base64.encode64(admin+ ":" + password).chomp}
```

but it doesn't work.

I also tried this solution from another link:

```
popup = RAutomation::Window.new(:title => /Authentication/i)        
popup.text_field(:index => 0).set('XXXXXX') # USER ID 
popup.text_field(:index => 1).set('YYYYYYYYY') # PASSWORD
popup.button(:index => 1).click
```

but it doesn't see the dialog box.

What are the other possible solutions for this? I cannot ask users to change their passwords for them to login.